# How can I update database every X days from server

Tags: database-versioning

I wasnt sure where to post this or what I should use for this. I recently learned that Twitch updates every single day and gives 1 random user a golden kappa face. I want to know how it's done, and what they use for to do this.

I asked a friend and he came with a link to https://www.infoq.com/articles/db-versioning-scripts I tried finding something about Database versioning but can't realy figure out what it is, or if this realy is what I'm looking for(?).

Could someone link me to some articles that can explain this too a beginner? or answer what I'm realy looking for.

I didn't wnat to do this with PHP because it whould requier a user to be online. I need it to update without a user been online (if possible).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This heavily depends on the Database engine or the stack you are using. Generally speaking, each of the big Database Servers (MSSQL, Oracle, etc.) has a service running in the background for these scheduled events.

For example the Microsoft SQL Server uses its [SQL Server Agent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_Server_Agent) to do this. Basically it allows you to schedule all different kind of tasks, including executing SQL scripts at certain intervals. Setting this up is as easy as clicking through a wizard.

You can also schedule these events by having your own service running in the background (programmed in the language of your choosing) and simply executing database scripts whenever you wish.

Comment: aah, that makes alot more sence now. thanks for your answer, I'll look into it